# Raster Resolution - Will not display past certain scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, scale, mosaic

I just created a mosaic of a couple hundred digital elevation models in ArcGIS desktop. The mosaic only appears at the raster resolution. I am working with a very large area and need the scale of my map to be about 1:1,000,000. I am wondering what I need to do to have the raster appear in the area I need it to. I obtained the data from the USGS and it is already at a very fine resolution (1/3 arc second from the USGS, 1x1 cell in ArcGIS). All rasters were in the same coordinate system, same number of bands, etc.

Comment: What sort of mosaic? Mosaic Dataset, raster dataset (classic mosaic), VRT.. if you're using a mosaic dataset it sounds like the path to the raster has changed from the time of creation and ArcGIS can only find the overviews.. you can repair data sources by providing the correct path. Relative paths in mosaic datasets are not allowed (reference https://community.esri.com/thread/45789 among many). If you're accessing over a network use the full UNC path to the images.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - it is a classic mosaic. My paths are intact and would not have changed as I have not moved the data since downloading it. I am wondering if it is a resolution issue since I am working with such high resolution data.

Comment: The resolution shouldn't be a problem, it's just math to display regardless until you reach the limit of floating point number storage. What raster format are you using? There could be a broken pyramid level, you could try rebuilding pyramids either with ArcGIS or with GDALAddO but make sure you overwrite or remove the existing pyramids, both tools tend to keep existing levels unless they are specifically told to overwrite (-clean with GDALAddO).